# Datagrid without height and width eating tons of memory

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have question why does this happening. I am loading data from SQL(about 3300 records) When I use Grid.Column in my datagrid without Width and Height it eats almost 900MB of memory and it also takes like 40 seconds to succesfully load records. But when I add Width and Height into datagrid it eats only 100MB and it instantly loads all records from SQL

Button control for filling datagrid

```
da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from ContactsMain;", cs);     
ds.Clear();
da.Fill(ds);
dg.ItemsSource = ds.DefaultView;
```

xaml datagrid:

```
 <Grid Margin="0 15 0 0">
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

       <DataGrid x:Name="dg" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,-350"/> <!-- Eats 900MB memory-->

<!--<DataGrid x:Name="dg" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,-350" Width="860" Height="322"/> instantly load records, 100MB eated-->
 </Grid>
```

Could anyone explain me why is this happening only cuz width / height?

Comment: Is the Grid inside a vertical StackPanel?

Comment: The datagrid virtualises its contents. It normally only generates the WPF cells that will be visible, and maybe enough to page down once or twice. Is setting the size to zero causing it to load all the data? If you set width and height, and then scroll to the end of the list, does it use 900MB?

Comment: @Clemens Yes it is

Comment: @RobinBennett Just scrolled to the end and it used only +20 MB

Comment: WPF datagrid without size boundation do not perform very well, this is due to the fact that grid add non visible data also when size is not given. Try to give only column width (no height) and you should still see performance impact. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/sizing-options-in-the-datagrid-control

Comment: Then the Grid and the DataGrid obviously get their maximum height, which means the DataGrid loads *all* rows at the same time. With a fixed height it won't do that due to [virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls).

Comment: @Clemens Kinda understand. But shouldn't it get dimensions when I have setted up ColumnDefinitions?

Comment: No, how would that affect the height? Even with a RowDefinition (w/o fixed Height) the Grid would grow as large as it wants.

Comment: @Clemens Ok I understand. But what do I do when user scale application? I don't want to have fixed height and width on window. If he maximalize the window now, datagrid will stay on the middle. Is it possible to make it responsive?

Comment: Use a Grid only, not a StackPanel. A Grid *does* limit the size of its child elements.